# Is it possible make a JPanel trigger an event when one of the elements inside changes?

Tags: java, swing, events, methods, listener

I have a JPanel with various Checkboxes inside. Instead of adding a listener to every single checkbox, I'd like to execute a method when any of them changes. If there is a way to do this, or maybe if there is a better way to do this, please tell me.

Comment: show us your code..how it looks..

Comment: Create a helper method that takes a single listner.  The helper will walk the JPanel children and add listners to all.  When one fires, forward to the single listner passed in the helper.

Comment: Nothing out of the box, you need one listener per-component. On the bright side: in real-world applications you most probably have a (f.i. presentation) model that has properties bound to children's state: then you can listen to that model and trigger whatever you need on changes

Comment: The code is auto generated by my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and I don't know how to access it. EDIT: This came out wrong. I can of course gain access to relevant parts of the code.

Comment: It turns out that I can select every Checkbox and my IDE can create a single Listener that handles every box. This solves my problem, but I don't think it's a general answer so I won't post it as one.

Comment: And this is why all Swing GUIs should be coded by hand, until the programmer understands Swing backwards and forwards.

Comment: @Gilbert: +1. The funny thing is however, once programmers know Swing backwards and forwards (and sideways and upsidedown), they wouldn't DARE let an IDE code their Swing. Self-respecting coders, that is ;-)